# How exactly does post increment of a pointer work?

Tags: c, pointers, post-increment

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int i, myarr[] = {15,3,27};
  int *ptr=&myarr[1];

  printf("%d\n",*ptr++);
  printf("%d\n",++*ptr);

  ptr=myarr;

  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    printf("%d", *(ptr+i));

  return 0;
}
```

In the part where post-increment of a pointer is used, why is it not printing out 4, but 28?

output

```
3
28
15328
```

Comment: The 28 is pre-increment of the value in the array

Answer (score 3):

`printf("%d\n",*ptr++);` points to `3`, reads the 3, increments the pointer and returns the 3 to be printed.

`ptr` now points to 27

`printf("%d\n",++*ptr);` points to the `27`, increments the 27 to 28 in the array, returns 28 to be printed.  `ptr` unchanged.

Comment: If you intend to pre-increment the pointer, and then dereference it, use `*++ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

In `*ptr++`, `++` has precedence over `*`, so the expression is `*(ptr++)`. This takes the value of `ptr`, separately increments `ptr`, and uses the value from before the increment with `*`. Since before the increment, `ptr` points to the `3`, `*ptr++` evaluates to 3. The increment leaves `ptr` pointing to the `27`.

In `++*ptr`, the `*` must be applied first, so the expression is `++(*ptr)`. Then `*ptr` is the thing `ptr` points to, which is the `27`, and `++` increments it and produces the value after the increment. So the `27` is changed to 28, and the value of the expression is 28.